# Hibernate : how to create JPQL by concatenating strings?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to find out a way to concatenate strings to create a JPA native query. At present I have 3 queries just for having 1 or 2 different words. For example:

```
String queryAsc = select emp.id,role_id from employee left join roles 
                         on roles.id = emp.role_id      
                         where emp.id = :id
                         order by employee.created_date asc;

String queryDesc = select emp.id,role_id from employee left join roles 
                         on roles.id = emp.role_id
                         where emp.id = :id
                         order by employee.created_date desc;
```

Just because of the word difference of "asc" vs "desc", I have to write 2 different repository methods with JPA query as:

```
@Query(value = queryAsc,
       countQuery = countToMyEmployees, nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object[]>  findMyEmployeesAsc(@Param("id") String id, Pageable pageable);

 
@Query(value = queryDesc,
       countQuery = countToMyEmployees, nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object[]>  findMyEmployeesDesc(@Param("id") String id, Pageable pageable);
```

Is there a way to concatenate two strings in JPA query to avoid this kind of repetition?

Comment: You should drop the idea of creating a request through spring concatenating. Thing about using `Crinteria API` or `QueryDSL` or `JooQ` to programmatically create you custom requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Sort from the caller.

```
 if (condition) {
    obj.findMyEmployees("123",pageableObject , new Sort("employee.created_date "));
    } else {
    obj.findMyEmployees("234",pageableObject ,new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"employee.created_date"));
    }
```

And rewrite the query as given below :

```
String query= select emp.id,role_id from employee left join roles 
                         on roles.id = emp.role_id
                         where emp.id = :id;
@Query(value = query,
       countQuery = countToMyEmployees, nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object[]>  findMyEmployees(@Param("id") String id, Pageable pageable, Sort sort);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This did not give me direct sorting as sorting and pagination can not be used together here in this specific way. However, your ans gave me direction on what to look for and I ended up using sorting option as part of pagination object which worked with JPA native query. Thank you